# Get SharePoint Group Permissions Via PowerShell

Tags: 2010, permissions, powershell

I am looking for a PowerShell command to get the permissions of a SharePoint group on a securable object.
I have googled for a while but without success.

I am aware of the GetUserEffectivePermissionInfo method offered by the SPSecurableObject.
But this method only gives permissions of a user.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

I don't have one that takes a specific object as input, but this may help.  It will list out the role assignments on web, list, items for users and SharePoint groups.

```
Start-SPAssignment -global    
$sites = Get-SPsite -limit All

    foreach ($site in $sites)
    {
        foreach ($web in $site.allwebs)
        {
            Write-Host -BackgroundColor green -ForegroundColor white $web.url
            $web.RoleAssignments

            foreach ($list in $web.lists)
            {
               If ($list.HasUniqueRoleAssignments)
               {
                    Write-Host -BackgroundColor yellow -ForegroundColor black $list.Title
                    $list.RoleAssignments

                    foreach ($item in $list.Items)
                    {
                        If ($item.HasUniqueRoleAssignments)
                        {
                            Write-Host -BackgroundColor red -ForegroundColor yellow $item.UniqueId
                            $item.RoleAssignments
                        }
                    }
               }
            }
        }
    }
Stop-SPAssignment -global
```